# NSMutableArray: how to fill it with data, release it, fill it with data again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray in my app which I initiate like this:

H-FILE

```
NSMutableArray *noteBookContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *noteBookContent;
```

M-FILE

```
@synthesize noteBookContent;
```

I then have a method in which I open a txt file and read its contents into a temp NSString and slices this NSString into different bits which are then put into the NSMutableArray. Like so:

```
    NSString *tempTextOut = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                             error:&error];

self.noteBookContent = [[[tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n[DIVIDER]\n"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

My **big question** is what happens if I repeat the same process a couple of times. Is there a need to release the noteBookContent before I read new data into it? Is there a chance of data being messed up, e.g. if one noteBookContent has 10 items (all called FRUIT) and the next noteBookContent has 5 items (all called SALAD), may I end up with SALAD, SALAD, SALAD, SALAD, SALAD, FRUIT, FRUIT, FRUIT, FRUIT etc.?

Sorry if this is obvious, but I don't really understand what happens in the moment that I read new data into an NSMutableArray which already contains old data.

Thanks for any explanations!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you’re not actually changing the contents of the array—you’re replacing the object entirely. The old value of `noteBookContent`—the NSMutableArray instance—gets released by the property assignment (the `.noteBookContent = ...`), and replaced with a new, separate NSMutableArray that’s created by the `-mutableCopy` call. A more efficient way to do it would be this:

```
[self.noteBookContent removeAllObjects];
[self.noteBookContent addObjectsFromArray:[tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n[DIVIDER]\n"]];
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is this more efficient? Is it actually saver? I like it better as it makes more sense. Sorry if all of this is obvious!

Comment: This way, the existing mutable array doesn’t get deallocated and doesn’t have to clean up its memory—it can reuse the space it already has.

Comment: @n.evermind - It is maybe more efficient because you do not need to realloc a a new `NSMutableArray` each time you load a file, I say maybe since emptying the array will in itself have a cost. Which least costly should be measured by Instruments. But if you never actually change the contents of the array after the file is loaded, then using an immutable `NSArray` is the way to go.

Comment: @Noah I actually tested this today and it crashed my app as nothing was found in the noteBookContent anymore. I don't know why this is... your code makes sense, but if I replace it with my line of code, it will crash the app. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** Call stack at first throw...

Comment: This is the code:   `//[self.noteBookContent removeAllObjects];
  //[self.noteBookContent addObjectsFromArray:[tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n[DIV]\n"]];
  
  self.noteBookContent = [[[tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n[DIV]\n"] mutableCopy] autorelease];` If I un-comment the bits you suggested (and get rid of my line), it will crash the app.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything, because you are using a property. This property automatically handles the memory management of your mutable array.